# Bug caused by non printable character embedded by Visual Studio

Tags: ide, editor, xcode8, visual-studio-2017, control-characters

I have some cross platform code that I regularly share between Visual Studio and Xcode (and Vim).

At some point, I modified a string in this code, using Visual Studio.  That string somehow ended up with an errant '**^H**' control character (ASCII 0x08) embedded in it.

The trouble is, this control character is non-printable. It wasn't visible in Visual Studio, nor was it visible in Xcode.

Viewing the source in Vim, I could clearly see the problem. Vim helpfully displays the control character, and problem solved.

Interestingly, when viewing the source via Xcode I can navigate through the string with the cursor - it clearly knows the character is there, as the cursor remains in the same location when traversing *over* the non-printable character.

So..

- How can I prevent Visual Studio from inserting errant control characters in the first place?  I presume this is a bug and should never happen.
- Is there any way to have Visual Studio display such control characters, without also showing spaces/tabs?
- Is there any way to have Xcode display such control characters, without also showing spaces/tabs?

Both environments have an equivalent '*Editor->Show Invisibles*' but it's a bit of an all or nothing.. It's not something I want on all the time.